# DPI Awareness per monitor V2 - calculate window size by client size with DPI <> 96

Tags: windows, winapi, dpi

When I start my developed DPI awareness per monitor V2 app with a DPI other than 96, I have problems to calculate the window size by a given client size.

I am calculating the window size by

```
    Dim rWinBase As RECT, dpi As Long
    
    dpi = GetDpiForWindow(mHwnd)
    
    AdjustWindowRectExForDpi rWinBase, GetWindowLong(mHwnd, GWL_STYLE), 0, GetWindowLong(mHwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE), dpi

    IForm_FrameHeightPixel = rWinBase.Bottom - rWinBase.Top
```

**This is working well with 96dpi solution**.

But when I start the app with other dpi than 96, the result is not matching.

In this case I need to correct the result with

Horizontal:

```
    Dim rWinBase As RECT, dpi As Long
    
    dpi = GetDpiForWindow(mHwnd)
    
    AdjustWindowRectExForDpi rWinBase, GetWindowLong(mHwnd, GWL_STYLE), 0, GetWindowLong(mHwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE), dpi
    
    Select Case dpi
    Case 120&
        rWinBase.Right = rWinBase.Right - 2&
    Case 144&
        rWinBase.Right = rWinBase.Right - 4&
    Case 168&
        rWinBase.Right = rWinBase.Right - 6&
    Case 192&
        rWinBase.Right = rWinBase.Right - 8&
    Case 216&
        rWinBase.Right = rWinBase.Right - 10&
    Case 240&
        rWinBase.Right = rWinBase.Right - 13&
    End Select
    
    IForm_FrameWidthPixel = rWinBase.Right - rWinBase.Left
```

Vertical:

```
    Dim rWinBase As RECT, dpi As Long
    
    dpi = GetDpiForWindow(mHwnd)
    
    AdjustWindowRectExForDpi rWinBase, GetWindowLong(mHwnd, GWL_STYLE), 0, GetWindowLong(mHwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE), dpi
    
    Select Case dpi
    Case 120&
        rWinBase.Bottom = rWinBase.Bottom - 5&
    Case 144&
        rWinBase.Bottom = rWinBase.Bottom - 11&
    Case 168&
        rWinBase.Bottom = rWinBase.Bottom - 17&
    Case 192&
        rWinBase.Bottom = rWinBase.Bottom - 23&
    Case 216&
        rWinBase.Bottom = rWinBase.Bottom - 30&
    Case 240&
        rWinBase.Bottom = rWinBase.Bottom - 37&
    End Select
    
    IForm_FrameHeightPixel = rWinBase.Bottom - rWinBase.Top
```

This cannot be the right solution. How do others to get correct results for inverse calculation of window size by client size with dpi other than 96?

Comment: Of course I am adding the calculated frame width and height to the given client size and set the result with setwindowpos. This is not shown here.

Comment: Depending on your application manifest (or absence of manifest) of the application doing the computation, the computation may be wrong, by design, since it sets the base for your application awareness to DPI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process in other terms check your app's awareness to DPI first

Comment: The settings are set by    
SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext dpiPER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2
SetThreadDpiHostingBehavior DPI_HOSTING_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT
This is done and all other DPI awareness stuff is running

Comment: This can also be seen, when I run with 96dpi and with running app I switch to other dpi. I get the new size for the window in WM_DPICHANGED. But when starting app with another dpi already set before, AdjustWindowRectExForDPI brings wrong results

Comment: You should put that in the question, this cannot be guesses reading your code

Comment: The first argument to [AdjustWindowRectExForDpi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-adjustwindowrectexfordpi) is an in/out parameter. The code posted passes an empty (or uninitialized) `RECT` in. If this isn't the *real* code, please show a [mcve].